# Using Live Property Explorer with ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox

Has anyone successfully used VS2015 Live Property Explorer to inspect ComboBox items? There is no obvious way to select or hover ComboBox items when the "Enable Selection" button is ON.

- If I click "Enable Selection" first, clicking on the ComboBox doesn't open it.
- If I open the dropdown first, clicking on "Enable Selection" closes the dropdown.

I also tried manually traversing through the hierarchy in Live Property Explorer, but the dropdown list is not part of the ComboBox hierarchy.

Or am I missing something simple?